# CXF WSDL namespace without slash

Tags: cxf, cxf-client

I generate a WSDL with Apache CXF 3.3.0 from Java classes, and I get this :

```
xmlns:tns="http://impl.service.ti.commun.metier.civitas.fr/"
```

I don't understand why tns ends with "/", so I check source Apache CXF, and i found that JaxWsImplementorInfo call PackageUtils (https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/common/util/PackageUtils.java) method which returns :

```
return "http://" + String.join(".", parts) + '/';
```

So, I have an end slash.

I would like get this:

```
xmlns:tns="http://impl.service.ti.commun.metier.civitas.fr"
```

How do that ?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: I believe you can annotate your class to enforce other than default namespace or provide the package-namespace mapping when generating the wsdl ( `-t` parameter)

Comment: Probably but the client call without "/" and I can't modify client.